# Part of shell script not getting executed

Tags: firefox, scripts

I have just started taking baby steps into shell scripting. My script goes something like this:

```
firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com
clear
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp start
cat somefile
```

Both the new tabs open up in Firefox and then the terminal stops further execution (shell does not go back to showing prompt though, it's still running Firefox). If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then it terminates the Firefox window and terminal gets back to initial terminal state.

How can I rewrite the code so that all the lines of code work properly (I do want Firefox to open up first preferably)? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use at least an & at the end of your commands and you may want to use nohup and or redirect error mesages. http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php . without the & your script waits for FF to end. If you close ff, rather then hitting ctrl-c, your script will proceed to clear .....

Comment: OK let me take a look at that link. Thank you bodhi :)

Comment: OK so now I understand why nothing after ff worked.  Now I've added an ampersand at the end of "firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com" so it now looks like "firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com &" .  Now the script reaches until sudo and asks for password. Then this occurs :-

(process:4682): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Comment: @Ajay add an ampersand & at the end of Firefox line

Comment: Well off by a minute :)

Comment: probably ask a new question as your original question is answered.

Comment: OK , thanks Serg and bodhi. And special thanks for informing about nohup. Its something i wanted to do at a later stage. Now its already done :) New question coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the ampersand(&) to the end of the first line in your script, or use `nohup`.

This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously. The shell will immediately return the return status of 0 for true and continue as normal, either processing further commands in a script or returning the cursor focus back to the user in a Linux terminal.

`nohup` catches the hangup signal  while the ampersand doesn't ,this means when running a command using & and exiting the shell afterwards, the shell will terminate the sub-command with the hangup signal `kill -SIGHUP PID`, while `nohup` catches the signal and ignores it.

So now your script would look like:

```
firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com & 
clear
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp start
cat somefile
```

As the OP said the last version(used nohup):

```
nohup firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com  & 2>/dev/null
clear
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp start
cat somefile
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing and got it to work. I also added nohup which was something I needed, based on comments above. Also, I redirected the GTK warning messages to dev/null so that they dont get in the way. For future reference, here's the final code (only 1 line changed) :-

nohup firefox -new-tab -url google.com -new-tab -url yahoo.com & 2>/dev/null

Thank you Maythux :)

Comment: @Ajay you are welcome friend